# how to create a pending intent inside of a BroadcastReceiver class?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create I broadcast intern inside of a broadcast receiver but I don't think I'm entering the right code for it. How should the pending intern look for the broadcast receiver? I want to send a text message. And need the pending intent to send it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to create I broadcast intern inside of a broadcast receiver but I don't think I'm entering the right code for it.

It is no different than any other `PendingIntent`, other than you have to use the passed-in `Context` object, since `BroadcastReceiver` is not a `Context`:

```
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent incoming) {
    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0));

    // do stuff with PendingIntent here
}
```

Comment: follow on question about "do stuff with PendingIntent here": I'm trying to send the PendingIntent from a BroadcastReceiver to a separate app (i.e., different package).  I'm trying to use AlarmManager to send it.  However the line AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  indicates that the method getSystemService(String) is undefined within the onReceive.  Is there a different way to send the PendingIntent?

Comment: @PeteH: "indicates that the method getSystemService(String) is undefined within the onReceive" -- call `getSystemService()` on the passed-in `Context`.

Comment: Great advice...that worked!  Now I'm uncertain if I've set up the alarm correctly.  I tried alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+2000, pendingIntent); but when I return to the app receiving the pendingintent it is being entered through onResume instead of onReceive.  Is the alarm set up correctly?

Comment: @PeteH: I have no idea what you are talking about. I suggest that you open a fresh StackOverflow question.